# Image placement using html and css

Tags: html, css

I am going to arrange images

This is html code

```
<div class="imagearea">
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="http://www.tawbaware.com/maxlyons/sample_JPEG.jpg" />
    <img class="subimg" src="http://www.tawbaware.com/maxlyons/sample_JPEG.jpg" />
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
</div>
```

css code

```
<style>
    .imagearea{
        width:100%;
        position:absolute;
    }

    .subimg{
        width:200px;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
    }
</style>
```

I am going to arrange images
When the images change the line, sub images of next line is arranged to image (that the height is the smallest ) of top image.
you can check it in http://jsbin.com/ezoyag/1/edit
But if I have set the height style of subimg class statis size (ex height:200px) and then I can see the good result.
And I'd like to set the height style auto.
For it I have to use only html and css

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want the images to not have a fixed height, but you want every line to be aligned to the highest image.

To do that you need to add a wrapper div around each image group:

```
<div class="imagearea">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="http://www.tawbaware.com/maxlyons/sample_JPEG.jpg" />
    <img class="subimg" src="http://www.tawbaware.com/maxlyons/sample_JPEG.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
    <img class="subimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_(animated,_small).gif" />
  </div>
   ...
</div>
```

And add to the css:

```
.row{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kuy48/)

**Update**

when setting the height to auto, you are telling the image to scale the height according to width, so it will maintain aspect ratio, the browser controls it, and the image might appear shorter than you expect.

You can try using `max-width:100%` and remove the height instead, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kuy48/1/ , there is not other way that i can think of, to do what you want unless you set a fixed height

Comment: Thanks, but i have not to use row div. and same same

Comment: If you can't use a wrapper div, then you can't do it (at least not easily)

Comment: sorry, i mean i have not to use row div and i can see the same result on the jsfiddle. check http://jsbin.com/onelur/1/edit, please

Comment: It's NOT the same result, compare your previous link and you can see the images are not aligned there, where as here, every image in the line is aligned. If what you want is the images to fill their parents, you have to use `max-width: 100%;` with no height

Comment: I have to use height:auto

Comment: check http://jsbin.com/onelur/1/edit, please. i have used wrapper div. but i cannot see the result that i want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34826/discussion-between-sea-guy-and-ftom2)